# MongoDB: How to get all objects from one array inside one Collection field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

At the moment, I have the problem that I can't find a document by its ID and then get the Grades.

Grades consist of multiple elements, and each of them has multiple fields.
So, an arrays with multiple objects.

I basically just want to get the grades corresponding to the ID of the document.

My Collection

```
    {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5c6eba356fd07954a489067c"),
       "StudentName" : "David",
       "StudentAge" : 28
        "Grades": [{"subject", "grade"}, ...]
    }
    {
      same
    }
```

My code so far. Unfortunately I can't get any further,
since I haven't found anything remotely helpful on the interent for hours

```
   Document findByIdQuery = new Document(ID, new ObjectId(id));
   Filterabel<StudentEntity> grades = mongoCollection().find(findByIdQuery);
```

also tried

```
 Filterabel<StudentEntity> grades = 
            mongoCollection().find(findByIdQuery).projection(  
            Projections.fields(
            Projections.computed("grades", lt("grades.qty", 20) )))
```

Comment: How does your Grades class looks like?

Comment: String subject, String grade. very simple. Is that important?

Comment: There are maximum 20 arrays

Comment: I dont understand this part   "Grades": { 0: ["subject", "grade"], 1["subject","grade"] }. What are 0, 1?

Comment: omg sry. It is an array with multiple objects of course. I updated it

Comment: @Nemanja I updated everything. There was an misconception

Comment: "Grades": [{"subject", "grade"}, ...] Did you miss key value pairs here? Sholud't it be something like [{"subject":"some random subject", "grade":"some grade"}]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
 MongoCollection<Document> customCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("<YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME>");
            BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("<YOUR_OBECT_ID>"));
            FindIterable<Document> cursor = customCollection.find(criteria);
            MongoCursor<Document> iterator = cursor.iterator();
        
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Document doc = iterator.next();
                List<Document> grades = doc.get("Grades", List.class);
                System.out.println(grades);
                for(Document grade : grades){
                    String subject= grade.get("subject", String.class);
                    String grade= grade.get("grade", String.class);
               }
               
                  
            }
            iterator.close();
```

Comment: I cant do that because I am using mongoCollection wich is returning class StudentEntity

Comment: I can not use doc.get